# Show validation when user selects specific radio button

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have two radio buttons (yes/no) in `React.js` with `Formik` and `Yup` packages used in my projects.

I want to provide a validation message using schema when the user selects the NO option out of the two.

I am able to provide the required validator with `Yup` though.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried following one and it worked,

```
yup
  .string()
  .test("is-no", "value cannot be No", value => value !== "no")
  .validate("A")
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(data => console.log(data.message));
```

Also, this is straight validation, was not used in any form.

To use this in form, you could reuse the schema but not use `validate` as part of the schema.

for example, your schema can be,

```
yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string(),
  yesOrNoField: yup
    .string()
    .test("only-yes", "Please select YES only", value => value !== "no"),
  anyNumberField: yup.number().required(),
});
```